# show loading modal in ember action

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, ember-cli

I have action on button click which sends data to server with ajax, I want to show loading model when user click on the button.

```
 addInvoices:function(){
            window.$('#loading-modal').modal('show')
            $.ajax({
              ..
            }).done(function (data) {
              ..
            });
            window.close();
        }
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're opening the modal, sending the AJAX request, then immediately closing the modal. Javascript isn't going to wait for the asynchronous request to finish before running your `window.close()` method; that's the whole point of asynchronous code. You need to put the close *inside* the promise, not after it.

```
window.$('#loading-modal').modal('show')
$.ajax({

}).done(function (data) {
    window.close();
});
```

Comment: ajax needs too much time and it is sync request, so the question was different

Comment: ember waits action completion and than shows modal, i want to show modal as soon as click button  (during ajax call)

Comment: If you make it a synchronous call, then you're going to block Javascript's only thread and the browser won't be able to display the dialog. Also, running the call synchronously doesn't make it faster.